# C# EXT App.direct.fname is not a function

Tags: c#, ext.net

I try to create a confirmation box in code behind. While the Confirmation function is called correctly, when I click the "Yes" button in the dialog I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: App.direct.DoYes is not a function

```
public void Confirmation(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        X.Msg.Confirm("Confirm", "Do you want to create test for this selection:", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
        {
            Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "App.direct.DoYes()",
                Text = "Yes"
            },
            No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
            {
                Handler = "wndRnd.Close()",
                Text = "No"
            }
        }).Show();
    }

[DirectMethod]
    public void DoYes()
    {
          //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a UserControl?  If so Ext.NET is using a naming convention of App.direct.[UserControl].DoYes() to avoid any conflicts with a possible the DoYes() event in the main or in another UserControl.  I always use the DirectMethodProxy attribute on the UserControl class name.  This defines what that [UserControl] name in App.direct.[UserControl].DoYes() will be.

```c#
using Ext.Net;

[DirectMethodProxyID(IDMode = DirectMethodProxyIDMode.Alias, Alias = "UC")]
public partial class SampleUserCtlClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    [DirectMethod]
    public void DoYes()
    {
        X.Msg.Alert("Message", "Hello from UserControl").Show();
    }
}
```

So merging both your question and this example, if your direct event was created in this UserControl it could be called using:

App.direct.UC.DoYes();